# Will Steve the train engineer be mad?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

This is a basic $Z$- score question. I would just like to know if I solved it correctly.

Train cars for the Crandic Railway Company carry $25$ standard-sized containers. The weight of each container is described by a distribution with a mean of $380$ pounds and a standard deviation of $50$ pounds. Steve, the train engineer, becomes upset if a train car contains more than $10,000$ pounds. What fraction of train cars would make him angry.

Mean of a train car $= 25 \cdot 380 = 9500$

SE for a train Car $= (25 \cdot 50) / \sqrt{50}  = 250$

$(9500 - 10000) / 250  = 2$

$1-(Z \leq 2) = 1-0.9772 = 0.0228$

$2.28\%$ of train cars will make Steve angry..

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Welcome. Please proofread your post and see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) on how to better format your mathematics.

Comment: Note that you should write a "by a *normal* distribution", not just "by a distribution". There are many different distributions, and it's important to specify which one you mean.

Comment: I copied the question from the book Applied Stats for Engineersand Physical Scientists. In this case the ambiguity is not mine. However, I do not believe that it causes much confusion because the normal distribution would the easiest (subjective) way to solve this problem. Other distributions say Poisson or Bernoulli would clearly not be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Note that a train contains more than 10000 pounds if and only if it is more than 2 standard deviations **to the high side** of the average. So the answer is approximately 1.35%

Comment: You may be conflating train cars with "standard-size containers". 25 containers are loaded onto each train car.

Comment: From what I understood, each train car carries 25 parcels. Thus, each train car is a sample of parcels with mean xbar.